# Show that $\{x \mid A_0 + \sum x_i A_i \succcurlyeq 0 \}$ is convex

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-matrix-inequality, spectrahedra

> Let $A_0, A_1,\dots,A_m$ be symmetric matrices. Let $x \in \mathbb R^m$ and define $$A(x) := A_0 + \sum_{i=1}^m x_i A_i$$ Show that the set $C := \{x \mid A(x) \text{ is positive semidefinite}   \}$ is convex.

---

For a set $C \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, I know of a few ways to show that it is convex:

1. Show that $\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2 \in C$ for all $x_1, x_2 \in C$ and $\lambda \in [0, 1]$.
2. Show that $C$ is an intersection of convex sets (for example halfspaces).

This is easy to show using the first method, but I am struggling to show that the set is convex using the second method.

**My question**

The second method above uses the "outer construction" of the set which I am not comfortable with. Is there some trick to applying this method? How could I show that my set $C$ is convex using this method?

Last, are there other methods for showing a set is convex other than the two I have listed above? (I know with additional assumptions it might be easier, but I am thinking about the general case)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1430571/339790)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $B \succeq 0$ if and only if $v^\top B v \ge 0$ for all $v \in \mathbb R^n$.
Thus,
$$
\{x \mid A(x) \succeq 0\}
=
\bigcap_{v \in \mathbb R^n} \{x \mid v^\top A(x) v \ge 0\}$$
and, since
$$
x \mapsto v^\top A(x) v
$$
is a linear mapping, the right-hand side is an intersection of convex half spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I want to offer a third way to prove.
There are operations that preserve convexity. One of them is the inverse image of a convex set.
You can take a look at section 2.3.2 of the book of Boyd and Vandenberghe[Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/) to read more.

You can prove that a set is convex by showing that the set is an inverse image of a convex set under an affine function.
Here take $f(x) = A_0 + \sum x_i A_i$. Then observe that $C$ is inverse image of Semidefinite cone $S_n^+$ under affine function $f$.